# Get the hWnd of the non-client "close" button [x] (win32)

Tags: winapi

My app needs to display an info balloon pointing to the `upper-right` corner `[x]` button indicating the window has to be closed by clicking the `pointed [x]` button.

for this reason I need to get the `[x]` button `hWnd` or if known its (undocumented) resource Id. Do you guys know how to do this with plain `win32?`

I have tried other alternatives dealing with non-client element metrics but they all gave unconsistent results (consider my app runs from `W2K` to `W8`)

thanks

Comment: You could probe for it by sending WM_NCHITTEST messages.  When you get HTCLOSE then you found the Close glyph.

Comment: Since you say that you need to support Windows 2000, you cannot use the `WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX` message. Instead, you have to use Active Accessibility to locate the Close object and then ask for its `accLocation`.

Comment: WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX gives unreliable info, I have never used Active Accessibility, I have been watching it a bit and it seems those MS complicated APIs; any tip on where to get some code example doing something similar?

Answer (score 3):

The close button there is not a window, and it does not have a separate `HWND`. Instead, it is painted along with possibly other elements by underlying `WindowProc` as a part of non-client area.

Comment: how do you know that? Please don't take me wrong; I'm not challenging you. But I'd like to know if your very possible comment is published somewhere, if you read the code on a debugger or if it's just your guess. Thanks

Comment: This is pretty easy. Visual Studio comes with `Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe` It enumerates all windows and shows to you, you can do the same via [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will see it is not a real window.