# Windows console application - Is it possible to detect (and handle) the window close (X) button hit?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

*I don't want to deflect the button hit or ignore the close event. I just need to run some cleanup code.*

Let me tell you what I've tried so far:

***atexit()***

***_onexit()***

***SetConsoleCtrlHandler()***

***~QCoreApplication()***

No code set by these is being executed.
The process just get killed when I press the X.

I certainly can make a windowed app and solve this, but is there a solution for a console application?

Thanks!

Comment: Related - different lang but may shed some clues cos still Windows and still console - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4646827/4386278

Comment: tl;dr SetConsoleCtrlHandler sounds right - perhaps show a [mcve] of that approach

Comment: Mind you, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abf09824-4e4c-4f2c-ae1e-5981f06c9c6e/windows-7-console-application-has-no-way-of-trapping-logoffshutdown-event?forum=windowscompatibility seems to suggest this has become difficult in "recent" years

Comment: On another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12988732/14972751) it's pointed out that close button is not a real window. See [TITLEBARINFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-titlebarinfoex) structure only stores coordinates of close button. Notice that there's no `HWND`. I say, you could try detecting mouse clicks onto those coordinates.

Comment: *I just need to run some cleanup code.* -- Isn't that what class destructors can handle?  Create a class, make a global instance, and in the destructor, put the clean up code there.

Comment: `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` is the correct and official way to detect the console window being closed. However, since Windows 7, the callback is no longer triggered during system logoff/shutdown. So, for that, create a hidden window via `CreateWindow/Ex()` and have it handle `WM_(QUERY)ENDSESSION` messages, or `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` messages from `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If `atexit` isn't firing, it stands to reason that destructors aren't either. Instead, the process is being hard-terminated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sounds like a good answer!

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings, the official sample only works for Ctrl+C.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function

Comment: @user814412, instead of going through such complication, I'd create a windowed app